# How to handle 1-N relation ship in DataNucleus?

Tags: java, mysql, persistence, jdo, datanucleus

[image]
Please help to solve below problem
**Scenario**

Our object structure is shown as above. Having one Java Persistence capable Object named 'User.java' and User.java contains List of 'Us

```js
public class FXUserDAOImpl implements FXUserDAO {

  private TOVOConvertor<FXUserTO, FXUserVO> tovoConvertor =  null;
  private PersistenceManagerFactory pmf;

  public FXUserDAOImpl() {
  this.tovoConvertor = new FXUserVOTO();
  this.pmf = JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory("TALOS");
 }

 @Override
 public Object persist(FXUserTO to) {
  FXUserVO vo = tovoConvertor.convertTO(to);  
  PersistenceManager pm = pmf.getPersistenceManager();
  Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();
  Object id = null;
  try {
   tx.begin();
   FxUserManagementMonitor.monitor.debug("Persisting : " + vo);
 
   pm.makePersistent(vo);
   tx.commit();
   id = pm.getObjectId(vo);
   FxUserManagementMonitor.monitor.debug("Persisted Object Id : " + id);
  } catch (Exception e) {
   FxUserManagementMonitor.monitor.error("Exception persisting data : " , e);
   throw new DataManagementRuntimeException(PlatformExceptionEnum.QUERY_SQL_EXCPETION,"Failed to execute persist ",e);
  } finally {
   if (tx.isActive()) {
    tx.rollback();
   }
   pm.close();
  }
  FxUserManagementMonitor.monitor.debug("Persisted Successfully "+id);
  return id;  
 }

 @Override
 public List<FXUserTO> retrieveAll() {

        PersistenceManager persistentManager;
  Transaction transaction;
  List<FXUserTO> toList = new ArrayList<>();  
  persistentManager = pmf.getPersistenceManager();
  transaction = persistentManager.currentTransaction();
  try {
   transaction.begin();
   FxUserManagementMonitor.monitor.debug("Retrieving Extent...");
   
   Extent<FXUserVO> voExtend = persistentManager.getExtent(FXUserVO.class, true);
   Iterator<FXUserVO> iterator = voExtend.iterator();
   iterator.forEachRemaining(eachVo -> {toList.add(tovoConvertor.convertVO(eachVo));});
   transaction.commit();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   FxUserManagementMonitor.monitor.error("Failed to retrieve all ...",e);
 
   throw new DataManagementRuntimeException(PlatformExceptionEnum.QUERY_SQL_EXCPETION,"Failed to execute retrieveAll ",e);

  } finally {
   if (transaction.isActive()) {
    transaction.rollback();
   }
   persistentManager.close();
  }
  FxUserManagementMonitor.monitor.debug("Successfully retrieved all ...");
 

  return toList;

 }

}
```

'UserGroups'. Also we are having two DAO classes to persist and retrieve User and UserGroups.

1. First we insert UserGroups using UserGroups DAO, Say Group_1,Group_2 and Group_3
2. Second We Insert User which contains UserGroup Group_1,Group_2.

What we expect is,  All User information will be saved to User table and only links to Group_1,and Group_2 will be kept in that table. But we are getting INVALID SQL Query Exception. As follows. Actually Its trying to enter new record to UserGroup Table

```js
@PersistenceCapable(identityType=IdentityType.APPLICATION,table="FXUserVO")
public class FXUserVO   implements TalosVO {

   @PrimaryKey
   @Column(name ="userId",jdbcType = "VARCHAR")
   @Persistent
   private String userId;
    
   @Element(column="userId")
   @ForeignKey(name="FK_GROUPS_FXUSERVO")
   @Persistent
   private List<UserGroupVO> groups;
   
   ------  
}


@PersistenceCapable(identityType=IdentityType.APPLICATION,table="UserGroupVO")
public class UserGroupVO   implements TalosVO {

   @PrimaryKey
   @Column(name ="groupId",jdbcType = "VARCHAR")
   @Persistent
   private String groupId;
    
   @Column(name ="groupName",jdbcType = "VARCHAR")
   @Persistent
   private String groupName;
    


}
```

Exception in thread "main" com.evermore.talos.platform.datamanagement.api.exception.DataManagementRuntimeException: Invalid SQL QUERY > Failed to execute persist 
    at com.evermore.talos.services.fxservices.fxusermanagementapi.generated.dao.FXUserDAOImpl.persist(FXUserDAOImpl.java:52)
    at com.evermore.talos.services.fxservices.fxusermanagementapi.generated.dao.FXUserDAOImpl.persist(FXUserDAOImpl.java:1)
    at com.evermore.talos.services.fxservices.fxusermanagementapi.generation.FXUserDAOImplTest.testFXuser(FXUserDAOImplTest.java:56)
    at com.evermore.talos.services.fxservices.fxusermanagementapi.generation.FXUserDAOImplTest.main(FXUserDAOImplTest.java:35)
Caused by: javax.jdo.JDODataStoreException: Insert of object "com.evermore.talos.services.fxservices.fxusermanagementapi.generated.vo.UserGroupVO@23c30a20" using statement "INSERT INTO `USERGROUPVO` (`GROUPNAME`,`GROUPID`,`USERID`,`GROUPS_INTEGER_IDX`) VALUES (?,?,?,?)" failed : Duplicate entry 'Group1' for key 'PRIMARY'
NestedThrowables:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'Group1' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:543)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.jdoMakePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:717)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.makePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:738)
    at com.evermore.talos.services.fxservices.fxusermanagementapi.generated.dao.FXUserDAOImpl.persist(FXUserDAOImpl.java:46)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'Group1' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:935)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3970)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3906)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2524)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2677)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2549)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2009)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5098)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1994)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.datasource.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:98)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.datasource.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:98)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ParamLoggingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ParamLoggingPreparedStatement.java:393)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.SQLController.executeStatementUpdate(SQLController.java:432)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.request.InsertRequest.execute(InsertRequest.java:398)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSPersistenceHandler.insertObjectInTable(RDBMSPersistenceHandler.java:162)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSPersistenceHandler.insertObject(RDBMSPersistenceHandler.java:138)
    at org.datanucleus.state.StateManagerImpl.internalMakePersistent(StateManagerImpl.java:3369)
    at org.datanucleus.state.StateManagerImpl.makePersistent(StateManagerImpl.java:3345)
    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.persistObjectInternal(ExecutionContextImpl.java:1987)
    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.persistObjectInternal(ExecutionContextImpl.java:2084)
    at org.datanucleus.store.types.SCOUtils.validateObjectForWriting(SCOUtils.java:1445)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.scostore.ElementContainerStore.validateElementForWriting(ElementContainerStore.java:289)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.scostore.FKListStore.validateElementForWriting(FKListStore.java:928)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.scostore.FKListStore.internalAdd(FKListStore.java:534)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.scostore.AbstractListStore.addAll(AbstractListStore.java:137)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.java.CollectionMapping.postInsert(CollectionMapping.java:157)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.request.InsertRequest.execute(InsertRequest.java:507)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSPersistenceHandler.insertObjectInTable(RDBMSPersistenceHandler.java:162)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSPersistenceHandler.insertObject(RDBMSPersistenceHandler.java:138)
    at org.datanucleus.state.StateManagerImpl.internalMakePersistent(StateManagerImpl.java:3369)
    at org.datanucleus.state.StateManagerImpl.makePersistent(StateManagerImpl.java:3345)
    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.persistObjectInternal(ExecutionContextImpl.java:1987)
    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.persistObjectWork(ExecutionContextImpl.java:1830)
    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.persistObject(ExecutionContextImpl.java:1685)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.jdoMakePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:712)
    ... 5 more

Comment: `Duplicate entry 'Group1' for key 'PRIMARY'` So you have a record with that primary key and attempt to INSERT a new one. Fix your persistence code

Comment: But my requirement is different. I only want to link UserGroup with User. So i am not even sure,  1 to N persistence will solve my problem

Comment: Whatever your "requirement" is, you are trying to persist multiple objects with the same PK, hence the error. So fix your persistence code! If you want to REFER to an object then you use "getObjectById" and use that!

Comment: So what change I need to do to link user object with user group.

Comment: How can anyone say "what to change" when you dont post the actual code that you use for setting up the relations and persisting?!

Comment: I had added both annotated class for User and UserGroup... Please dont be rude...

Comment: You did not (and still have not) post code saying how you ASSOCIATE the relationships. You dont post code how you PERSIST the objects.

Comment: @Niel , Sir Added DAO code for persistence. Please help..... Thanks

Comment: and where is the code of how you set the relation fields? What data is already in the database? Which makePersistent() call does the exception appear at? This is known as "debugging" ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139156/discussion-between-shineed-basheer-and-neil-stockton).